# Phonegap/Cordova GoogeMaps plugin layering

Tags: html, cordova, cordova-plugins

Hello I'm programming an app with the google maps plg for Cordova. On the wiki is said I have to put the HTML elements in the map canvas for top layering. It works OK, except the list-view after I press my action button. The view gets put behind and I move the map.
Any ideas?

Here is the HTML code

```html
    <div id="map_canvas">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#" data-icon="home">Home</a>
            <h1>Where is my gang</h1>
            <a href="#" data-icon="bars" onclick="callAnothePage()">Chat</a>
        </div>

        
        <div id="noga" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

            <a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a">Actions...</a>
            <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="b">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Choose an action</li>
                    <li><a href="#">View details</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Disable</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

       </div>
    </div>
```

[image: maps layering]

Comment: are you using [this](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) plugin ?